# Pet BAG Assignment(Class file in Java)-Cannot run the program in Eclipse IDE through apporto

Tags: java

[The image is the error message i get as well as showing the eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axT7c.png)The problem I am having is I cant get my code to run through the eclipse IDE each time I click run it doesn't run and just gives me an error message "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches." I am trying to create a PET class file through java.
here is the code for my assignment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Pet {
private String petType;
private String petName;
private int petAge;
private Map<Pet, Integer> dogSpace; // contains the Pet and days it is staying
private Map<Pet, Integer> catSpace; // same but for cats

private int daysStay;
public double amountDue;


/**
* Pet, base class for Dog and Cat
* @param String name - Name of the Pet
* @param int age - Age of the Pet
* @param String type - Cat | Dog
*/
public Pet(String name, int age, String type) {
this.petName = name;
this.petAge = age;
this.petType = type;
this.dogSpace = new HashMap<Pet, Integer>(); // use a hashmap to keep track of pets in the shelter
this.catSpace = new HashMap<Pet, Integer>(); // the Pet object is the key, and the days they are staying is the value.
}

public void checkIn(Pet pet) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many days will your " + this.petType + " be staying?");
int days = (int) in.nextInt();
this.daysStay = days;

switch(this.petType) {
case "Dog":
if(days > 1) {
System.out.println("Do you require grooming services?");
String needsGrooming = in.next();
boolean grooming;
if(needsGrooming.equals("yes") || needsGrooming.equals("y")) {
System.out.println("We will groom your dog...\n");
grooming = true;
}
else {
grooming = false;
}
this.checkInDog((Dog) pet, days, grooming); // handle the special dog cases
}
else {
this.checkInDog((Dog) pet, days, false);
}
break;
case "Cat":
if(this.catSpace.size() < 12) {
this.catSpace.put(pet, days);
}
break;
default: // Throw an exception if a pet other than a Cat | Dog is booked.
in.close(); // Close the scanner before exiting.
throw new RuntimeException("Sorry, we only accept cats and dogs");
}
in.close(); // Close the scanner when there is no exceptin thrown.
}

/**
* Contains extra steps for checking in a dog.
* @param pet - The dog object.
* @param days - Number of days staying.
* @param grooming - Whether or not the dog needs grooming.
*/
private void checkInDog(Dog pet, int days, boolean grooming) {
pet.setGrooming(grooming);

try {
if(this.dogSpace.size() < 30) { // Enforce the maximum of 30 dogs in the shelter.
this.dogSpace.put(pet, days);
pet.dogSpaceNbr = this.dogSpace.size() + 1;
pet.setDaysStay(days);
}
}
catch (Exception e) { // For some Map objects, calling size() on an empty collection can throw an error.
System.out.println("You're our first visitor!");
System.out.print(pet);
this.dogSpace.put(pet, days);
pet.dogSpaceNbr = 1;
}
System.out.println("" + pet.getPetName() + " will miss you, but is in good hands.");
}

/**
* Check out the desired Pet and calculate how much is owed for the boarding.
* @param pet - The pet you wish the check-out.
* @return amountDue - The amount of money owed for the boarding.
*/
public double checkOut(Pet pet) {
double fee;

if(pet.getPetType() == "Dog") {
double groomingfee = 0.0;

Dog animal = (Dog) pet;
int days = this.dogSpace.remove(pet);
double weight = animal.getDogWeight();
if(weight < 20) {
fee = 24.00;
if(animal.getGrooming()) {
groomingfee = 19.95;
}
} else if (weight > 20 && weight < 30) {
fee = 29.00;
if(animal.getGrooming()) {
groomingfee = 24.95;
}
} else {
fee = 34.00;
if(animal.getGrooming()) {
groomingfee = 29.95;
}
}
System.out.println("Fee Schedule:\n Boarding Fee: " + (fee*days) + "\nGrooming Fee: " + groomingfee);
animal.amountDue = (fee * days) + groomingfee;
return animal.amountDue;
}
else {
int days = this.catSpace.remove(pet);
fee = 18.00;
pet.amountDue = (fee * days);
return pet.amountDue;
}
}

public Pet getPet(Pet pet) { // Not sure why we need this.
return pet;
}

public Pet createPet(String name, int age, String type) {
switch(type) {
case "Dog":
return new Dog(name, age);
case "Cat":
return new Pet(name, age, "Cat"); // I have implemented the dog class, not the cat.
default:
throw new Error("Only Dogs and Cats can stay at this facility.");
}
}

/**
* Asks the user to fill in all of the attributes of a pet. Saves them directly to the object it was called on.
* @param pet - The pet you wish to update information on.
*/
public void updatePet(Pet pet) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the pets new name?");
pet.setPetName(in.next());
System.out.println("What is the pets age?");
pet.setPetAge(in.nextInt());
System.out.println("What type of animal is your pet?");
pet.setPetType(in.next());
in.close();
}

public String getPetName() {
return this.petName;
}

public int getPetAge() {
return this.petAge;
}

public String getPetType() {
return this.petType;
}

public void setPetName(String name) {
this.petName = name;
}

public void setPetAge(int age) {
this.petAge = age;
}

public void setPetType(String type) {
switch(type) { // while a switch is extra here, it will make it easier to add other pets.
case "Dog":
this.petType = type;
break;
case "Cat":
this.petType = type;
break;
}
}

public void setDaysStay(int days) {
this.daysStay = days;
}
}

public class Dog extends Pet {
public int dogSpaceNbr;
private double dogWeight;
private boolean grooming;

public Dog(String name, int age) { // automatically declares a pet of type Dog
super(name, age, "Dog"); // super is used to call the parent classes constructor
}

public double getDogWeight() {
return this.dogWeight;
}

public boolean getGrooming() {
return this.grooming;
}

public void setDogWeight(double weight) {
this.dogWeight = (double) weight; // casting a double here might be redundant, but it helps us to be sure
} // we don't get at type error

public void setGrooming(boolean value) {
this.grooming = value;
}
}

public class Cat extends Pet {
private int catSpaceNbr; // The number space the cat is in.

public Cat(String name, int age) { // automatically declares a pet of type Cat
super(name, age, "Cat"); // Calls the constructor of the parent class
}

public int getCatSpace() {
return this.catSpaceNbr;
}

public void setCatSpace(int number) {
this.catSpaceNbr = number;
}
}type here
```

I haven't tried much to fix the issue besides look up videos and now reach out for help just not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the Package Exporer or Navigator tab (right hand panel) right-click on the class that contains `public static void main` and choose Run as >> Java application.

When you have done that successfully you can run with the run button.